# How can I create a different set of metadata colums for each level of the folder hierarchy?

Tags: content-type, custom, metadata, subfolders

How can I create a different set of metadata colums for each level of the folder hierarchy? With content types? This seems to just create a new view unrelated to the actual files in a specific folder?

Comment: At least the view should differ, but rather the actual set of columns should be specific to folder level.

Comment: I tried with various settings of content types, but there are so many options and so far I didn't find the right one.